# OpenCV android initialization

Tags: android, opencv

I have written code that works on other systems for opencv, but on android I am having issues grabbing and passing images to my opencv algorithm.  Right now, I do not have any sort of preview set up in my android activity- is this okay?  I have no experience using opencv on android and need to have this done ASAP.

Right now I am initializing my camera object the same way I would on the computer-- which is obviously not right

```
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);
```

After looking at the sample code, I am still not seeing the initialization of the VideoCapture object anywhere.  Is this normal?

EDIT:

Finally, after a lot of research I realized I wasn't initializing opencv correctly in the activity.  Now I'm just not getting a value for

```
Mat img = new Mat();
camera.read(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install [Tegra Android Pack](https://developer.nvidia.com/gameworksdownload#?dn=tegra-android-development-pack-4-0r1) which comes with opencv installed on android studio. It also includes lots of example code.
The link can require registration.

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough.  I got it initializing properly by adding relevant display code, and fetched the frames from the interface, making them global so I can access the frames from different classes.  [This helped a lot.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6ywepfA_PU)